# Which preposition "at" or "of" to use in this case?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct in this case?

> We present our visualizations based on student data from a computer
>   science course **of** a German university.

or

> We present our visualizations based on student data from a computer
>   science course **at** a German university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to this, but personally, I would use "at" and here is why:

The simple explanation is, "at a German university is a prepositional phrase that describes the **location** of the course, not the data from the course.

My more complex explanation:
"Visualizations" is the subject. "Based on student data" is a descriptive prepositional phrase that serves an adjective for "Visualizations." "From a computer science course" is another prepositional phrase that describes where the data were obtained. "___ a German University" is a prepositional phrase that describes where the science course takes (or took) place. So I would conclude that the correct preposition would be "at" a German University.

I'm not a Grammar teacher, nor do I have a degree in Grammar. But I have written a good number of peer-reviewed journal articles and that is the usage I would try first. Of course, it could get kicked back for editing by peers.

So, if someone who is qualified to know the best preposition to use in this sentence, then I would defer to them.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are correct, but using "of" is awkward.  If you wanted to describe it as a possessive case, you could say:

> We present our visualizations based on student data from a German
>   university computer science course.

Otherwise, if you were to place it "German university" after "computer science course" then using "at" is more appropriate in colloquial English because it implies location.  @Fred is correct to, you could use "from" because that is what the course's origin is.